# .where query with comparison on Rails model returns an empty relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am a Rails noob, and this is my first SO post. So please be patient :)

I have a Rails model called "device" that stores a bunch of information about device. A lot of that information is stored in a serialized hash, because I thought I wouldn't need that info. But unfortunately now I do, so I have extracted the two pieces of information I need to attributes for the model using the following methods. Please pardon the bad, code I do intend to make it more readable :)

From schema.rb:

```
t.float    "charge_left"
t.float    "available_capacity"
```

From device.rb

```
def charge_left
  ((details['BatteryLevel'].to_f)*100).round
end

def available_capacity
  (((details['AvailableDeviceCapacity'].to_f.round(2))/(details['DeviceCapacity'].to_f.round(2))) * 100).round
end
```

Now I need to find devices which have available_capacity and charge left less than 10. But I get empty relation for every query possible, even though there are devices with the required attribute range.

```
irb(main):008:0> Device.first.charge_left
=> 66
irb(main):009:0> Device.where('charge_left > ?', 10)
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation []>

irb(main):007:0> Device.first.available_capacity
=> 7
irb(main):006:0> Device.where('available_capacity < ?', 10)
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation []>
```

Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks to me like use are using `charge_left` as both an instance method *and* the name of an attribute. Therefore, when you call `Device.first.charge_left` it is returning the value of the instance method and not the database column. You can only use .where to formulate queries based on the values of attributes, not instance methods.

You should write an instance method to set the `charge_left`:

```
def set_charge_left(available_capacity, device_capacity)
  self.charge_left = ((available_capacity.to_f.round(2))/(device_capacity.to_f.round(2))) * 100).round
  self.save!
end
```

Then in your controller (where you have access to your params) you can call it like this:

```
set_charge_left(details['AvailableDeviceCapacity'], details['DeviceCapacity'])
```

Comment: Ah! I didn't realize I couldn't use .where on a method. I was under the impression that using this was the way to set an attribute value using a method to extract the value from another attribute (in this case a serialized hash).

If I try a different method name to set the value of charge_left, as derived from the hash and then call where on charge_left, would that work?

In fact, could you tell me what I should do in my model to set the charge_left attribute from the details hash as (((details['AvailableDeviceCapacity'].to_f.round(2))/( details['DeviceCapacity'].to_f.round(2))) * 100).round?

Comment: Yeah, you just need to write an instance method in your model to set the attribute, and then call that method from your controller (where you have access to your details hash). See my edit.

Comment: @techtivist It seems Joel adequately answered your original question; it is customary to accept that answer. It is natural to have additional questions, but if it's not answered here then please feel free to post a new question.

Comment: @Matt My apologies, I tried upvoting Joe's first attempt, but it wouldn't let me since I didn't have enough reps. I left it open so that I could close it once I got it right with Joe's directions.